# Dumping struct in C

Tags: c, binaryfiles

Is it a good idea to simply dump a struct to a binary file using fwrite?
e.g

```
  struct Foo {
     char name[100]; 
     double f;
     int bar; 
  } data;

   fwrite(&data,sizeof(data),1,fout);
```

How portable is it?
I think it's really a bad idea to just throw whatever the compiler gives(padding,integer size,etc...). even if platform portability is not important.

I've a friend arguing that doing so is very common.... in practice.
Is it true???

Edit: What're the recommended way to write portable binary file? Using some sort of library?
I'm interested how this is achieved too.(By specifying byte order,sizes,..?)

Answer (score 3):

That's certainly a very bad idea, for two reasons:

- the same `struct` may have different sizes on different platforms due to alignment issues and compiler mood
- the `struct`'s elements may have different representations on different machines (think big-endian/little-endian, IEE754 vs. some other stuff, `sizeof(int)` on different platforms)

Comment: Even when portability isn't important, it means that your structs can't change, ever. Forget making names[101] or adding a field foo.

Comment: @karmakaze: you *could* work around that by sticking a version number field at the start, and making sure that when you change the struct you retain the old definition/code as well (perhaps under a new name), so that you can read the old layout and then convert to the new. But you still *shouldn't*.

Answer (score 3):

It rather critically matters whether you want the *file* to be portable, or just the code.

If you're only ever going to read the data back on the same C implementation (and that means with the same values for any compiler options that affect struct layout in any way), using the same definition of the struct, then the code is portable. It might be a bad idea for other reasons: difficulty of changing the struct, and in theory there could be security risks around dumping padding bytes to disk, or bytes after any NUL terminator in that char array. They could contain information that you never intended to persist. That said, the OS does it all the time in the swap file, so whatEVER, but try using that excuse when users notice that your document format doesn't always delete data they think they've deleted, and they just emailed it to a reporter.

If the file needs to be passed between different platforms then it's a pretty bad idea, because you end up accidentally defining your file format to be something like, "whatever MSVC on Win32 ends up writing". This could end up being pretty inconvenient to read and write on some other platform, and certainly the code you wrote in the first place won't do it when running on another platform with an incompatible storage representation of the struct.

The *recommended* way to write portable binary files, in order of preference, is probably:

1. Don't. Use a text format. Be prepared to lose some precision in floating-point values.
2. Use a library, although there's a bit of a curse of choice here. You might think ASN.1 looks all right, and it is as long as you never have to manipulate the stuff yourself. I would guess that Google Protocol Buffers is fairly good, but I've never used it myself.
3. Define some fairly simple binary format in terms of what each `unsigned char` in turn means. This is fine for characters[*] and other integers, but gets a bit tricky for floating-point types. "This is a little-endian representation of an IEEE-754 float" will do you OK provided that all your target platforms use IEEE floats. Which I expect they do, but you have to bet on that. Then, assemble that sequence of characters to write and interpret it to read: if you're "lucky" then on a given platform you can write a struct definition that matches it exactly, and use this trick. Otherwise do whatever byte manipulation you need to. If you want to be really portable, be careful not to use an `int` throughout your code to represent the value taken from `bar`, because if you do then on some platform where `int` is 16 bits, it won't fit. Instead use `long` or `int_least32_t` or something, and bounds-check the value on writing. Or use `uint32_t` and let it wrap.

[*] Until you hit an EBCDIC machine, that is. Not that anybody will seriously expect your files to be portable to a machine that *plain text files* aren't portable to either.

Answer (score 1):

How fond are you of getting a call in the middle of the night?  Either use a #pragma to pack them or write them variable by variable.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this sort of foolishness is very common but that doesn't make it a good idea. You should write each field individually in a specified byte order, that will avoid alignment and byte order problems at the cost of a little tiny bit of extra effort. Reading and writing field by field will also make your life easier when you upgrade your software and have to read your old data format or if the underlying hardware architecture changes.